# JMeter Recording with applications using Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, proxy, jmeter, load-testing, recording

Having a bit of an issue recording through JMeter with applications using Google Maps.

Whenever I enable the proxy on Firefox (localhost:8080), google maps will stop displaying on any page I navigate to while the proxy is active.

This is causing me problems because the majority of the functionality I'm looking to record on my application resides within the Google Maps window on the page, and this is being displayed as a blank white window.

Help is appreciated,
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I bet that you have a bunch of `Received fatal alert: unknown_ca` and `Software caused connection abort: recv failed` messages. This is how Google protects itself from [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks.

In general I wouldn't recommend to performance test Google Maps themselves, it should be tested by Google engineers, so the common practice is to [exclude external sites](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/exclude-external-site-td5717770.html) and focus on your application.

If you still need to record Google Maps actions and convert them to JMeter requests it is still possible, however this is not what usually being done in the performance testing world, you can use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi) or one of the following sniffer tools:

- [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
- [HTTP Analyzer](http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/)
- [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

And construct relevant requests manually basing on sniffer output.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for your prompt answer. The error that I'm getting is as followed: "ReferenceError: google is not defined." It's not GoogleMaps itself that I need to test, but the overlays that are on top of GoogleMaps, which are generated by our software. And without being able to test these overlays then I'm unable to test about 80% of the application as the functionality relies on these map overlays so much. Does the BlazeMeter plugin cost money and will it record everything to my Recording Controller, or will it go to some cloud? Guess there is no other way around it? Thanks

Comment: `google is not defined` looks like a JavaScript error to me. JMeter is not a browser and it cannot execute client-side JavaScript. In regards to the plugin - it's free to use and it can export recorded data into JMeter's .jmx file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue while recording the script via JMeter proxy, the text-box where we obtained auto suggested locations via google API never rendered. We also saw "ReferenceError: google is not defined" JavaScript error. Here is what I did as a workaround

1. Installed a chrome plugin (BlazeMeter) to capture all the HTTP requests, headers and cookies sent via the browser without the need of a proxy. (Make sure you close all tabs and keep only your application one open)
2. Manually created the samplers in the JMeter script for all requests that translate into the transaction I was trying to perform
3. Manually added the header and cookie information as required for each request
4. Used JMeter java API to programatically read request/response headers and cookies set respectively via parameterization.